# Animate opacity of an element on page-load using CSS3

Tags: css

Using CSS 3, is it possible to animate the opacity of an element from 0 to 1 when the page containing the element has been loaded? Possibly with a delay of 1 to 2 seconds...

Comment: it doesnt seem possible; therefore, I'd go with Jquery or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has no idea about load event. You should take a look at this **[combination of jQuery and CSS3](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/GFckp/)**.

Or, since you are about adding some JS anyway, why not to **[animate the whole thing in JS](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/rNnW7/)**? This will give you better cross-browser solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As spliter replied

Jquery has the solution for managing the opacity........

For example

```
$("#mydiv").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
```

The above code can be used to set the opacity to 50%.....(This is Jquery)

Or

You can use .fadeTo() property(of jquery) to enable opacity on page load event

visit http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ for the complete detailed information... Jquery is quite easy to learn

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
$(function(){
                    $('#spe').hover(function(){

                        $(this).css("opacity","0.50");
                        $(this).animate({top:"80px"},500);
                    },function(){
                        $(this).css("opacity","0.3");
                        $(this).animate({top:"126px"},500);
                    });
                });
```

or you can use opacity in animate method.